# Implement a function component that accepts one props "name"

Tags: reactjs

My code won't pass the test and I'm a bit lost on the syntax. This is what I'm trying to do:

- Implement a simple function component that accepts one props "name"
- and renders an h1 element with the text "Hi {name}" where {name} is
- the value in the prop "name"
- if name is empty (empty string, undefined or null), render "Hi "

My code in React:

```
export default class WithProps extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: "value",
    };
  }

  render() {
    const { name } = name;
    if ({ name } == "" || undefined || null) {
      return <h1>Hi</h1>;
    }
    return <h1>Hi {this.props.name}</h1>;
  }
}
```

Comment: You've created a class component, not a function component. https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components

Comment: @MattU the "export default class WithProps extends Component" was there by default and I had to follow this template.

Comment: That isn't a function component though, so it definitely won't work if the requirement is to use a function component.

Comment: @MattU fair enough, the instructions weren't very clear. I found an answer that helped though. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of a functional component with your code

```
    export const WithProps = ({ name )} => { 
      const [name, setName] = React.useState();
    
      return (
        <h1> 
        {name ? `Hi ${name}` : 'Hi'}
        </h1>
      );
    }
    <WithProps name="World" />
```

Here is a class component with your code

```
export default class WithProps extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: "value",
    };
  }

  render() {
    const { name } = this.props;

    return (
        <h1> 
        {name ? `Hi ${name}` : 'Hi'}
        </h1>
      );
  }
}
    
    <WithProps name="World" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const WithProps = ({ name }) => {
  return <h1>Hi{name && ` ${name}`}</h1>;
};

export default WithProps;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Live Demo**

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

**App.js**

```
import "./styles.css";
import WithProps from "./WithProps";

export default function App() {
  return <WithProps />;
}
```

**WithProps.js**

```
export default function WithProps({ name }) {
  return <h1>{`Hi ${name ?? ""}`}</h1>;
}
```